# Sending all form inputs using JQuery each() and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

So I use the each() method to get each input's value and send it with ajax to save it in the Database, here's the code:

```js
$("#my-form :input").each(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"index.php?option=com_questionnaire&task=stock_reponse",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            name: this.name, 
            answer: this.value
        },
        success: function(result){
            // alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

So the problem is, when I keep the alert, it works just fine.. all the answers are sent and saved correctly, when I remove the alert it doesn't work !

Obviously I can't keep the alert, and I don't understand what's causing this behavior!

How can I solve this ?

**EDIT:** Sorry I had a problem somewhere else in the code, not even related to this..

Comment: can you check whether your server side is thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because one bracket is missing!

$("#my-form :input").each(function(){

```
     $.ajax({
        url:"index.php?option=com_questionnaire&task=stock_reponse",
        type: "post",
        data: {name: this.name, answer: this.value },
        success: function(result) {
         //alert(result);
        } // <-- this was missing?
```

});

Have you tried to totally remove the success part? Im not sure but that could work :)

Comment: the `$.ajax()` brackets are also missing.

Comment: No it's not the brackets, sorry I just deleted them by mistake when I copied the code here. I edited the post. And I also tried removing the success part, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why this issue is occurring. I found that one closing bracket and semicolon is missing. But I am assuming that while copy paste, it was missed.

But you can use one technique to resolve for time being rather than RnD. It would be like a hake.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    // Some text here
}, 1000);
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why the setTimeout. I just want to send the answers of the form, I don't need to do anything in the callback!